# C# Convert.ToInt16(String) C Equivalent

Tags: c#, c, unsigned, signed

What is the C equivalent of Convert.ToInt16(String) method of C#?
In my case my string is a char array.
Thanks

Comment: @Ionut, In C++ you don't know what type is 16-bit. In C it will be `int`.

Comment: @Kirill: Not really. C doesn't require int to be 16bit. It actually states that An unsigned int can hold all the values between 0 and UINT_MAX  inclusive. UINT_MAX must be at least 65535. The int types must contain at least 16 bits to hold the required range of values. So yes, in C you are sure it's at least 16 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/).

Comment: I know there are some bit complications in some cases, but that one was enough to solve my case. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [atoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atoi) or strtol.

```
int n = atoi(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/)

`sscanf("%i", myCharPointer, &myIntVar);`